# How to disable RDP acces to a particular VBoxHeadless VM?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, rdp

Having an RDP access enabled for a production VM seems like a huge security hole, so I'd like to disable it as soon as an OS is installed and SSH access is configured.

I've tried

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "myvm" --vrdp off
```

and

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "myvm" --vrdp=off
```

but anyway when I then

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm "myvm"
```

The VM starts up with VRDP active.
**The only working way to disable VRDP I've found is starting the VM with "--vrdp=off" as a starting command parameter** like

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm "myvm" --vrdp=off
```

But can I save this choice? For a simple

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm "myvm"
```

to start without an RDP server?

PS: By the way, what does the letter 'V' in VRDP mean?

**UPDATE:** A silly thing I've asked about V :-] obvious that it stands for "virtual". The actual idea I meant asking this is how does it differ from the standard RDP, or is it exactly the same protocol and only a marketing trick to add the V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vrdp will always remain "on"/"enabled" for a "headless" configuration according to:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless

The "v" stands for "virtual" for the "virtual session"/"virtual machine."

Comment: A silly thing I've asked about V :-] obvious that it stands for "virtual". The actual idea I meant asking this is how does it differ from the standard RDP, or is it exactly the same protocol and only a marketing trick to add the V.

Comment: Probably "v" as it is RDP for the VM, so it is OS independent as long as it runs within VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <uuid|name> --vrde off
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
# VBoxManage controlvm vmName vrde off
# VBoxManage controlvm vmName vrde on
```

instead of

```
# VBoxManage modifyvm vmName --vrde off
# VBoxManage modifyvm vmName --vrde on
```

"controlvm" works regardless the status of the VM or whether it is headless or not.

More info on [How to enable / disable VRDP access to VirtualBox VM regardless of state](https://serverfault.com/questions/1135660/how-to-enable-disable-vrdp-access-to-virtualbox-vm-regardless-of-state)

---

**Side Note I**: I couldn't reproduce your problem.

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvm emptyVM --vrde off

$ vboxmanage showvminfo emptyVM | grep VRDE
VRDE:                        disabled

$ vboxheadless --startvm emptyVM &
Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 7.0.8
Copyright (C) 2008-2023 Oracle and/or its affiliates

Starting virtual machine: 10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%

$ vboxmanage showvminfo emptyVM | grep VRDE
VRDE:                        disabled
VRDE Connection:             not active
```

---

**Note II:**

You can also use this to start "headless"

```
$ vboxmanage startvm emptyVM  --type headless
```