# How to enable / disable VRDP access to VirtualBox VM regardless of state

Tags: virtual-machines, rdp, virtualbox

In the documentation https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html

they tell you that you can use

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvm VM-name --vrde on
```

but that only works if the VM is off.

Can it be done while the VM is on? How?

--

**Glossary:**

RDP: Remote Desktop Protocol

VM: Virtual Machine

[VRDE](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html): VirtualBox Remote Desktop Extension

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Listing vms (to get the name)

```
$ VBoxManage list vms
"Debian_11_Server_64bit" {3d**6e14-3846-4673-aacb-726****283af}
"emptyVM" {8a**643a-f470-4ab0-931a-5da6****5ce4}
```

**- Enable/disable VRDP when the VM is OFF**

```
# Power off
$ vboxmanage controlvm emptyVM   poweroff
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%

# Turn off VRDP
$ VBoxManage modifyvm emptyVM --vrde off

# Turn on VRDP
$ VBoxManage modifyvm emptyVM --vrde on
```

**- Enable/disable VRDP when the VM is ON (or OFF)**

```
# We start the VM
$ vboxmanage startvm emptyVM  --type headless
Waiting for VM "emptyVM" to power on...
VM "emptyVM" has been successfully started.

# Try the previous command
$ VBoxManage modifyvm emptyVM --vrde on
VBoxManage: error: The machine 'emptyVM' is already locked for a session (or being unlocked)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 640 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

The VRDP settings cannot be changed with "modifyvm" when the VM is ON.

But we can still change them with "controlvm".

```
$ VBoxManage controlvm emptyVM vrde off

$ VBoxManage controlvm emptyVM vrde on
```

**- How can I know if it is enabled / disabled and the port?**

```
$ vboxmanage showvminfo emptyVM | grep VRDE
VRDE:                        enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 3394, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
VRDE port:                   3394
VRDE property               : TCP/Ports  = "3394"
VRDE property               : TCP/Address = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Enabled = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Quality = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/DownscaleProtection = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableDisplay = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableInput = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableAudio = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUSB = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableClipboard = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUpstreamAudio = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableRDPDR = <not set>
VRDE property               : H3DRedirect/Enabled = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/Method = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerCertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerPrivateKey = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/CACertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Audio/RateCorrectionMode = <not set>
VRDE property               : Audio/LogPath = <not set>
VRDE Connection:             not active
```

**- How can I change the PORT**

```
$ vboxmanage controlvm emptyVM  vrdeport 12345
```

**- Does the change done with "controlvm" persist when the VM is powered
off?**

Below we poweroff the VM, disable VRDP, poweron, modify VRDP, poweroff and check. Apparently, the change is persistent.

```
$ vboxmanage controlvm emptyVM   poweroff
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%

$ VBoxManage modifyvm emptyVM --vrde off

$ vboxmanage showvminfo emptyVM | grep VRDE
VRDE:                        disabled

$ vboxmanage startvm emptyVM  --type headless
Waiting for VM "emptyVM" to power on...
VM "emptyVM" has been successfully started.

$ vboxmanage showvminfo emptyVM | grep VRDE
VRDE:                        disabled
VRDE Connection:             not active

$ vboxmanage controlvm emptyVM  vrde on vrdeport 12345

$ vboxmanage showvminfo emptyVM | grep VRDE
VRDE:                        enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 12345, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
VRDE port:                   12345
VRDE property               : TCP/Ports  = "12345"
VRDE property               : TCP/Address = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Enabled = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Quality = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/DownscaleProtection = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableDisplay = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableInput = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableAudio = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUSB = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableClipboard = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUpstreamAudio = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableRDPDR = <not set>
VRDE property               : H3DRedirect/Enabled = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/Method = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerCertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerPrivateKey = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/CACertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Audio/RateCorrectionMode = <not set>
VRDE property               : Audio/LogPath = <not set>
VRDE Connection:             not active

$ vboxmanage controlvm emptyVM   poweroff
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%

$ vboxmanage showvminfo emptyVM | grep VRDE
VRDE:                        enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 12345, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
VRDE property               : TCP/Ports  = "12345"
VRDE property               : TCP/Address = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Enabled = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Quality = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/DownscaleProtection = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableDisplay = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableInput = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableAudio = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUSB = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableClipboard = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUpstreamAudio = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableRDPDR = <not set>
VRDE property               : H3DRedirect/Enabled = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/Method = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerCertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerPrivateKey = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/CACertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Audio/RateCorrectionMode = <not set>
VRDE property               : Audio/LogPath = <not set>
```